# Addon SDK. How I can make popup like this?

Tags: javascript, css, popup, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

It's possible to made popup like this?
[image]

Not contents in it. The style and position of popuping is interesting for me.
Under toolbutton, with arrow up to center of button.

The panel widget didn't do the same, it just popup in center of window.

How I can do this popup with Add-on SDK?

Comment: Sorry. The night do his job :) I found answer here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Firefox 30 and above, you can attach a `Panel` to a `ToggleButton` like this:

```
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    ...

    onHide: function(){
        button.state('window', {checked: false});
    }
});  

var button = require("sdk/ui").ToggleButton({
    ...

    onClick: function(state) {
        if (state.checked) {
            panel.show({
                position: button
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Specify where to attach the panel via `position` parameter in call to `Panel.show`; In this case, we're attaching it to the `ToggleButton`.

more information:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Attaching_panels_to_buttons

Answer (score -1):

The [`panel` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel) lets you create basic panels using HTML5 (+ Javascript and CSS, of course).

```
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("myFile.html")
});

panel.show();
```

Then there are Australis "View" panels, which are XUL-based and integrate better with the [Australis customization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm), e.g. it looks more Firefox-"native" and the "Views" are properly integrated when a ancestor toolbar button in the "hamburger menu". There is no SDK abstraction available ATM.

Comment: That's actually completely wrong, see the first answer.

Comment: @canuckistani I fail to see where my answer is wrong. You can "attach" an SDK panel to a button, sure. I never claimed you couldn't! I claimed that Australis View panels will look more native and integrate better, as in http://i.imgur.com/OBnw55H.png , which is entirely correct.

Comment: This looks fine to me: http://note.io/1rxCiY8 ...based on the question asked, which is mainly about the arrow, the border and the looks of the panel itself ( as he says, not the contents )

Comment: @canuckistani So what? Again I didn't claim panels are not panels. In fact I said the opposite, that you can create basic panels using the SDK panel API. I should have included the button example specifically instead of the generic one. In that regard the other answer is better, of course, no argument there. I then provided additional information regarding Australis View Panels, which are the new hot thing. Because OP and *other people* reading the answer might be interested in that as well.

Comment: You should have included the button example, because *that's what the question asked for*. You didn't really answer the question and added in some additional info that didn't help answer the question. That's a downvote.

Comment: @canuckistani It's your vote, so that's fine with me. But I still disagree with your reasoning.